# Do lowered reputation cap limit affect new badges? And why is my rep cap lowered anyway?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

So with the new rep cap badges available, I find myself putting in more time to answer questions, which is great.  But now I'm having a rep cap issue, and I find myself wondering about it.

Today I've managed to get 190 rep.  When I was at 150 earlier, I noticed that an upvote for an answer I had made disappeared, and my rep went down to 140.  No big deal.

But now I am at 190, and it appears that I can't get any higher than that.  I can't remember how many downvotes I made today, so I'm not sure if that's the problem, or if it's one of the other many vagaries of the rep cap system.  **Edit** - I've made one downvote today.

So my big question is, do I still count as having hit the cap, even though subsequent upvotes don't take me higher (Jon Skeet's tool shows them as counting as 0)?  And the second question is why I can't go any higher?  I've tried wading through all the various FAQs and Meta questions, but the cap really is quite frustrating to figure out in situations like this.

Edit - this is on SO, of course.

Comment: Pretty aggressive with the downvotes, aren't we? :\

Comment: "Recent Activity" should log your downvotes. Count them!

Comment: @Robert Harvey - I don't think I'm very aggressive with downvotes.  I tend to downvote spam questions a lot, but I'm no Rich B.  @John - ah, right, forgot about that little page.  Looks like I gave one downvote today.

Comment: Mmm, spam questions.  That probably explains it.  I never dv spam questions...waste of time.  By the time someone gets enough rep where they actually care about getting dv'd, they're generally not asking spam questions anymore.

Comment: Yes, I only ever downvote ones that have more than 1 rep.  But surprisingly, there's still quite a few of those.  Overall I'm a generally positive voter.

Comment: Could it be that you were at 205 (with an accepted answer) and then lost the accepted answer again?

Comment: @John - nope.  The only thing weird I saw happen today was a previous upvote for a question disappear.  I can only assume it was removed, or perhaps the question was deleted.  That was at around 150 rep.  I haven't gone higher than 190 all day.

Comment: @John - oh sorry, I misunderstood. I suppose that is possible, although I never saw myself over 190. It would probably have had to happen in a fairly short time period, I was checking quite constantly around the time it hit 190. So I'm a bit addicted  :p  But would that explain the rep cap?  And if so, does it count towards the rep cap badges?

Comment: Pretty sure it counts to the badges, my little addict ;) You hit the cap. You do not have to stay at 200 (or above).

Comment: We need a new badge, for asking about the reputation cap on meta; we can call it "A Little Addicted". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a question (and its answers) is deleted, the rep for your answers on that question is still reflected in your total rep, but doesn't show in the reports for the day.  That is, you will have earned the full 200 rep for the day, even though the reports don't show it.  Eventually, I assume, your rep will be recalculated and the rep for the deleted answer will be removed.  Hopefully, though, you'll have an upvote that wasn't counted due to the cap on that day to offset it.

Comment: Ah... this seems like the most likely possibility.  Any thoughts on whether today will count for the badges then?  It sounds like it should.

Comment: If you've been capped -- whether the report reflects it or not -- it should count towards any related badges.  I suspect too, that recalculations that would result in a previously capped day becoming uncapped, would not result in a badge being lost, though I'm not as sure about that.  It could be that your next badge at that level doesn't increase your badge count.

Comment: That makes sense from what I read from other meta questions about recalcs.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: "Rep recalc"? Those are rarer than waffle-coated unicorns.